# Jframe and Jpanel size won't work

Tags: java, swing, jframe, size, jpanel

I have a class Skeleton that makes a Surface and sets the size to 400x400

```
public class Skeleton extends JFrame {

    public Skeleton() 
    {
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI()
    {
        setTitle("");
        int height = 400;
        int width = 400;

        add(new Surface());

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width + getInsets().left + getInsets().right,
                                        height + getInsets().top + getInsets().bottom));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        //setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Skeleton sk = new Skeleton();
                sk.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then in the surface class I draw a line from (0,0) to (400,400) and when I run the code the bottom end of the diagonal ends off the panel.

```
class Surface extends JPanel 
{

    private void makediag(Graphics g, int size) 
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2d.drawLine(0, 0, size, size);

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        makediag(g, 400);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the size of the panel wrong or are the drawing coordinates different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of `JPanel` is wrong because you are setting preferred size for your `JFrame`.

Best way would be to override `JPanels` `getPreferredSize` method and to return your desired dimension.

```
protected Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(400, 400);
}
```

Also, be sure just to call `pack` for your `JFrame`. Don't call `setXXXSize` at all.

Comment: +1, also see [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/1048330)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javadoc for `pack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29):

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts
>   of its subcomponents.

Therefore the window is supposed to ignore its own preferred size and use the preferred size of its subcomponents. There's no reason to expect `setPreferredSize` to influence the size of the frame. It seems what you really want to do is to set the preferred size of the Surface to (400,400). That also saves you from having to work with insets.